# The background-color is spanning the width of my nav-bar, not the entire background

Tags: html, css, class, background-color

I'm new to programming and was hoping someone could help me with this one.

I have multiple pages and would like them all to be different colors. I wrapped all of my code in a class and then styled them like this:

```
.tech_page{   
    background-color: #F4C0CC;
}
```

And the body looks like this:

```
 <body>

    <div class="tech_page">

       <div class="nav-bar"> 
           <nav> <a href="/"><p class="nav-home"> Home </a> </nav>
           <nav> <a href='/tech'><p class="nav-tech"> Tech </p></a> </nav> 
           <nav> <a href='/about'><p class="nav-about"> About </p></a> </nav>
           <nav> <a href='/mindmap'><p class="nav-mindmap"> Mind Map </p></a> </nav> 
           <nav> <a href='/projects'><p class="nav-projects"> Projects </p></a> </nav>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

But only the nav bar is getting the background color! Everything else remains white. The entire span of the page gets the background color if I put a class on the body but I don't think that's clean code. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: where you have added  the class tech_page to your html code ??   in your code there is not an element witn this class

Comment: Sorry! That must have been confusing, it was just an error when I was writing the question. Fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the body use the class  tech_page you should add  the class

```
<body class='tech_page'>

    <div class="projects_page">

       <div class="nav-bar"> 
           <nav> <a href="/"><p class="nav-home"> Home </a> </nav>
           <nav> <a href='/tech'><p class="nav-tech"> Tech </p></a> </nav> 
           <nav> <a href='/about'><p class="nav-about"> About </p></a> </nav>
           <nav> <a href='/mindmap'><p class="nav-mindmap"> Mind Map </p></a> </nav> 
           <nav> <a href='/projects'><p class="nav-projects"> Projects </p></a> </nav>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

or  you could used

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.tech_page{   
    background-color: #F4C0CC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and for html

```
<body>

    <div class="tech_page">

       <div class="nav-bar"> 
           <nav> <a href="/"><p class="nav-home"> Home </a> </nav>
           <nav> <a href='/tech'><p class="nav-tech"> Tech </p></a> </nav> 
           <nav> <a href='/about'><p class="nav-about"> About </p></a> </nav>
           <nav> <a href='/mindmap'><p class="nav-mindmap"> Mind Map </p></a> </nav> 
           <nav> <a href='/projects'><p class="nav-projects"> Projects </p></a> </nav>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hey! 
Thanks for getting back to me, I tried this and it definitely works but I was told it wasn't clean code. Do you know of another way? I've tried using percentages to expand the height and width but it wasn't working too well. Do you think grid would fix this problem?

Comment: your comment is not clear  ..  your question is about a background  color related to a class  that don't appear in page  ..  .. my answer  suggest you of adding the class  to the right element  ..if you need  others css  attribue for the class  eg:  `height:100vh;`  (for a full height )..then add  also this value to the class ..  .. hope is clear ..

Comment: anyway  ... what do you mean with  "I was told it wasn't clean code." ?   .. the class (or ID)   is tipically for manage css  attribute to html tag ..

Comment: That's true, it is typically used for that. I was told by my teacher not to attach a class to the body tag though as it's not good practice. I was hoping there was a way with grid or width/height to solve the problem. Thanks for your help but I couldn't quite get height:100vh; working. Not sure if me or the code

Comment: I canìt see  all your code so i can't answer  for the height problem  .. but if you don't want  assit to body the class .. the you could  set body height and width:100% and the add  a nested  div with class  you need with heigh and width  100% and the background color .. but if you code have error  ..,this suggestion can't work  ..

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, that's not working either. Ahh well, I'll keep trying

Comment: anyway i have update  the answer  with a suggestion  hope is useful  ..

Answer (score 0):

By adding `height:100vh` in your tech_page class should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Either  write the css in any css file or write the same in style tag as given below.You can write similar css for newly created page.Note:Best practice is to create a css file and write css.Here only tech_page class background is changed ,if you want o change the whole page background you can write css for element css of top level div class.Try it.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">
     .tech_page{   
        background-color: #F4C0CC;
    }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="tech_page">

           <div class="nav-bar"> 
               <nav> <a href="/tech"><p class="nav-home"> Home </a> </nav>
               <nav> <a href='/tech'><p class="nav-tech"> Tech </p></a> </nav> 
               <nav> <a href='/about'><p class="nav-about"> About </p></a> </nav>
               <nav> <a href='/mindmap'><p class="nav-mindmap"> Mind Map </p></a> </nav> 
               <nav> <a href='/projects'><p class="nav-projects"> Projects </p></a> </nav>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for helping out, the css is in a css folder. Sorry! I should have been more clear. Do you have any thoughts on how to get the entire background one color?

Comment: Yes . just set height and width of your top level div to 100%.eg: .tech_page{   
    background-color: #F4C0CC;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

Comment: Just try it. :)